# Angular js, weather api search city and using enter key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-http

So the code allows me to show low and high temperature using the openweather api data.
 I can see the data perfectly, if i declare the value of the city in the input (ex: value ="houston")

but i want a function that takes the value i entered and when i hit the enter key, the  data displays.

This way i can see the data of any city i choose. 
Below is my code, runs perfect if i don't use the enterkey function inside ng-keydown and declare a value instead. so it must the way i use enterkey function in js file .

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($http) {

    var ctrl = this;

    var URL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily';
    var city = document.getElementById("search_box").value;
    var request = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: URL,
        params: {
            q: city,
            mode: 'json',
            units: 'imperial',
            cnt: '7',
            appid: 'd20b7e069e7858118979c0ed0b36f8b5'
        }
    }

    function enterkey() {
        var enterk = event.keyCode || event.which;

        if (enterk == 13) {



    $http(request)
        .then(function (response) {
            ctrl.data = response.data;

            console.log(ctrl.data);
        })

}}
})
```

```html
   

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/weatherangu.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular JS</title>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="myapp">

  
  <div id="content" ng-controller="DemoCtrl as ctrl">

    <img id="w_pic" src="../images/7day.png">
    <input type="text" id="search_box" placeholder="Enter City Name Here.." ng-keydown="enterkey()">

    <div id="weather_data">
       <h1 class="zero">{{ ctrl.data.list[0].temp.max| json }}</h1><br>
       <h1 class="zero">{{ ctrl.data.list[0].temp.min| json }}</h1>

      <h1 class="one">{{ ctrl.data.list[1].temp.max| json }}</h1><br>
      <h1 class="one">{{ ctrl.data.list[1].temp.min| json }}</h1>

      <h1 class="two">{{ ctrl.data.list[2].temp.max| json }}</h1><br>
      <h1 class="two">{{ ctrl.data.list[2].temp.min| json }}</h1>

      <h1 class="three">{{ ctrl.data.list[3].temp.max| json }}</h1><br>
      <h1 class="three">{{ ctrl.data.list[3].temp.min| json }}</h1>

      <h1 class="four">{{ ctrl.data.list[4].temp.max| json }}</h1><br>
      <h1 class="four">{{ ctrl.data.list[4].temp.min| json }}</h1>

      <h1 class="five">{{ ctrl.data.list[5].temp.max| json }}</h1><br>
      <h1 class="five">{{ ctrl.data.list[5].temp.min| json }}</h1>

      <h1 class="six">{{ ctrl.data.list[6].temp.max| json }}</h1><br>
      <h1 class="six">{{ ctrl.data.list[6].temp.min| json }}</h1>

              </div>
  </div>
  <script src = "../js/weatherangu.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything extra to use the enter key. Just enclose the input in a form with a submit input. Then use `ng-submit` to show the details when the enter key is pressed. Also, the functions you're calling from the view, need to be attached to the `$scope`. And with angular, you don't need to use DOM functions in the controllers, use `ng-model` instead.

#### HTML

```
<form action="" method="get" ng-submit="submitForm()">
  <input ng-model="cityName" type="text" id="search_box" placeholder="Enter City Name Here..">
  <input type="submit" style="display:none"/>
</form>
```

#### JS

```
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($http) {

    var ctrl = this;

    var URL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org...';
    var request = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: URL,
        params: {
            //use ng-model instead of getElementById
            q: ctrl.cityName, 
            mode: 'json',
            ...
        }
    }

    ctrl.submitForm = function() {
        $http(request)
            .then(function (response) {
                ctrl.data = response.data;
                console.log(ctrl.data);
            })
    }
})
```

I haven't tested it, but you should get the idea.

Comment: There should never be any dom code in an angular controller. Simple use of `ng-model` would remove it. Always think data model and binding methods first, not dom first

Comment: @charlietfl: yeah, you're right, I just extended the code of the OP. I will edit it and suggest it as well

Comment: i tried the ng- model like the code above "q:ctrl.cityName " but cityName is coming as 'undefined' . I made $scope.cityName = cityName; then q:cityName but getting "not defined"

Answer (score 0):

So, after getting suggestions from the members i was able to connect the input value to the value of the city by ng-model, this will create a two-way data-binding. I also had to manually use $watch to look for input value changes and re run the function to change the data dynamically as i type in the city name. If anyone finds any other  better,efficient or recommended way of doing this. Please feel free to comment.

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($http,$scope) {

    var ctrl = this;

    var URL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily';
    //var cityName = document.getElementById("search_box").value;


    $scope.request = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: URL,
        params: {
            q: 'london',
            mode: 'json',
            units: 'imperial',
            cnt: '7',
            appid: 'd20b7e069e7858118979c0ed0b36f8b5'
        }
    }
function test() {


    $http($scope.request)
        .then(function (response) {

            ctrl.data = response.data;
            console.log(ctrl.data);
        })
}
test();

    $scope.$watch('request.params.q',function () {

        test();

    })


})
```

```html
<!--<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/weatherangu.css">
 
  <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-app="wapp">
  
 
 
 <input type="text" id="searchbox" placeholder="Type City Name Here.." onkeydown="enterkey()" >
 
 <div id="posterdiv" ng-controller = "ctrl as vm">

  <p> {{vm.data | json}}</p>

 </div>
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 

 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
 
<script src = "../JavaScript/weatherangu.js"></script>
 
</body>
</html>-->

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/weatherangu.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular JS</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="myapp">

  
  <div id="content" ng-controller="DemoCtrl as ctrl">

    <img id="w_pic" src="../images/7day.png">


   <!--<form action="" method="get" ng-submit="submitform()">- -->
    <!--<input  type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.request.params.q" id="search_box" placeholder="Enter City Name Here..">-->
     <!--<input type="submit" style="display:none"/>-->
  <!--</form>-->


    <input  type="text"   ng-model="request.params.q" id="search_box" placeholder="Enter City Name Here..">


    <div id="weather_data">
{{
       <h1 class="zero">{{ ctrl.data.list[0].temp.max| json }}</h1><br>
       <h1 class="zero">{{ ctrl.data.list[0].temp.min| json }}</h1>

      <h1 class="one">{{ ctrl.data.list[1].temp.max| json }}</h1><br>
      <h1 class="one">{{ ctrl.data.list[1].temp.min| json }}</h1>

      <h1 class="two">{{ ctrl.data.list[2].temp.max| json }}</h1><br>
      <h1 class="two">{{ ctrl.data.list[2].temp.min| json }}</h1>

      <h1 class="three">{{ ctrl.data.list[3].temp.max| json }}</h1><br>
      <h1 class="three">{{ ctrl.data.list[3].temp.min| json }}</h1>

      <h1 class="four">{{ ctrl.data.list[4].temp.max| json }}</h1><br>
      <h1 class="four">{{ ctrl.data.list[4].temp.min| json }}</h1>

      <h1 class="five">{{ ctrl.data.list[5].temp.max| json }}</h1><br>
      <h1 class="five">{{ ctrl.data.list[5].temp.min| json }}</h1>

      <h1 class="six">{{ ctrl.data.list[6].temp.max| json }}</h1><br>
      <h1 class="six">{{ ctrl.data.list[6].temp.min| json }}</h1>
}}
     </div>
  </div>

  <script src = "../js/weatherangu.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```